# Why is RowDeleting event of GridView Called Twice automatically !

Tags: asp.net

Why does  RowDeleting event of GridView in ASP.NET WebForms Called Twice automatically(in Chrome) !!

I Checked by tracing the events, it's working fine in IE and FF, but Chrome creating this problem.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can put a condition in the `GridView_RowDeleting` to verify if the row is deleted or not then accordingly you can cancel the Rowdeleting by `e.cancel =true;`

Comment: It's working pretty fine in IE and FF, Only Chrome is creating this prob. It there any trick/hack to know why this event is called??

Comment: you are not calling any clientside script while deleting right?